# require(variable) causes the error Cannot find module "."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, require

I am using React and Node.js and I am trying to render images with the src attribute stored as a prop. But whenever I try to feed `require()` a path stored as a variable it gives me **this error**: Cannot find module "."

So I am wondering why require cannot handle a variable that points to a path but can handle the path itself? For example, this will result in the error mentioned above:

```
<MyComponent imageSrc='./image.jpg'/>
...
<img src={require(this.props.imageSrc)}/>
```

But this will work perfectly:

```
<img src={require('./image.jpg')}/>
```

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(this.props.imageSrc)`?

Comment: Require expects the file to be a node file with module.exports. The image does not have that, as it is a JPG file. You shouldn't need to require the image in order to display it, though, if it is in your public directory.

Comment: Why don't you use it like that: `<MyComponent imageSrc={require("./image.jpg")} />` and then `<img src={this.props.imageSrc) />` And as @RyanZ explained actually you don't need to require the image here.

Comment: @devserkan, thanks. That worked.

Comment: You are welcome. Then I will convert this comment into an answer this is the way you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the comments actually you don't need to require any image here. You can use relative paths in your src directories. But, for your situation this will work:

Use require when you pass your prop to your component:

```
<MyComponent imageSrc={require("./image.jpg")} />
```

And use this prop there like:

```
<img src={this.props.imageSrc} />
```

---

An alternative solution I've learned recently:

```
<img src={require( "" + this.props.imageSrc) } />
```

Comment: Can you explain why adding an empty string corrects this problem? `require(src)` causes this error for me. `require("" + src)` works. This makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: @DaveStein, I know it is weird :) It concatenates the variable with an empty string and hence returns a string. This is what require expects: a string.